# Vue.js net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING Webpack error

Tags: javascript, webpack, console, vue.js, chunked-encoding

While using Vue.js 2.3.4 in development on Chrome 58.0.3029 I keep getting this error in developer tools console:

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`

`:8080/__webpack_hmr`

Everything appears to be working OK, but after updating everything I still see this error and wondered if it's something I need to pay attention to.

Also, I want to clear out any unnecessary errors.

Comment: I have the same issue with nodejs 8 + vuejs 2.3.4 + chrome 58.0.30.29. I had to solve an issue at the startup regarding some npm version. But I cannot seem to fix the failed to load resource. It might come from the NodeJS 8 (https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware/issues/210) (They did a fix 2 days ago, so it might work in the latest nodejs

Answer (score 0):

There's a [pull request to fix this](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/pull/739/) in the webpack template repo, but it hasn't been merged as of this writing.

I've implemented the fix from the PR in several projects and it seems to work fine.

In `build/dev-server.js`, add `heartbeat: 2000` to the options object passed to `require('webpack-dev-middleware')` so it ends up looking like:

```
var hotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler, {
  log: () => {},
  heartbeat: 2000
})
```

Edit: it seems as though a [newer identical PR](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/pull/784/) was just accepted/merged.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler, {
  log: () => {},
  heartbeat: 2000
})
```

Worked for me, and also this:

```
var hotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler, {
  log: false,
  heartbeat: 2000
})
```

and you must run again `npm run dev` command.

Thanks to [#Jack Barham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1353451/jack-barham)

**Note: im using the PWA Template.**